# Is it possible to compute Betti numbers from number of vertices, edges, ...?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex, betti-numbers

I have two questions about complexes:

> **Q1.** Are two complexes of same number of vertices, edges,... necessary homeomorph?
>
> **Q2.** Is it possible to compute Betti numbers from number of vertices, edges, ...?

Comment: Does Q1 mean "Are two complexes with the same number ...."?

Comment: I reckon the only topological invariant that can be worked out using nothing but the counts of the simplices of each dimension is the Euler characteristic.

Comment: I suggest you consider the case of triangulated compact 1-dimensional manifolds and verify that $b_0$ and $b_1$ cannot be recovered from the numbers of vertices and edges.

Comment: The answer to Q1 is no. I think it is not even true for graphs, but I did not think of a counterexample. It should be not too hard to come up with. The answer to Q2 is also no, see for example Moishe Kohan's comment.

Comment: "betti" $\to$ "Betti" (Name of a mathematician)

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thanks for the clue. But why number of vertices, edges, ... can recover Euler characteristics? just accidentally? (Although Betti numbers cannot be recovered from Euler characteristics).

Comment: Your last "why" question is beyond the scope of what has already been asked and answered in the comments to this post. Nonetheless the "why" is indeed a very interesting theorem: $\sum (-1)^i \beta_i = \sum (-1)^i n_i$, where $\beta_i$ is the $i$th Betti number, and $n_i$ is the number of $i$-dimensional cells of the complex. You'll find a proof in any algebraic topology textbook.